# How to copy every n-th characters from one char array to another?

Tags: c

I have a program that reads file A and then copies the contents to file B.
I would like to write to file B every third character. I created a loop that rewrites every third item to a new char array. In file B I get strange characters. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 int main ()
 {
    int i;
    char full_string[100]; 
    char reduce_string[100]; 

    char file_name_for_read[128];
    char file_name_for_save[128];

    printf("Enter file name for read...\n");
    scanf ("%s", file_name_for_read);

    strcat(file_name_for_read,".txt");
    FILE *fileA;
    fileA=fopen(file_name_for_read,"r");

    printf("Enter file name for save...\n");
    scanf ("%s", file_name_for_save);

    strcat(file_name_for_save,".txt");
    FILE *fileB;
    fileB=fopen(file_name_for_save,"w");

    while(fgets(full_string, sizeof(full_string), fileA) !=NULL) 
    {

        for(i = 2; i < 100; i+=3)
        {
        reduce_string[i-=2] = full_string[i+=1];
        }
        fprintf(fileB, "%s", reduce_string); 
    }

    fclose(fileA);
    fclose(fileB);

}
```

Comment: Please, please, please, do **yourself** a favour and rewrite the loop body: `reduce_string[i-=2] = full_string[i+=1];`. Try not to change the control variable inside. Do simple things in many statements. **Trying to cram code into a single statement is not good practice**.

Comment: the typical paradigm for figuring out if something is n'th is to decide if it has the same remainder when divided by n ... so `if(x % n == y)` where x is your counter, n the the period and y is the phase (usually `0`, but can be anything from 0 to n-1) so read that as " if x mod n equals y" and read up on the modulus operator in C... that will solve part of your problem.

Comment: Don't use `fgets`.  If you want to write every third character, use `fgetc` and write every third character.

Comment: `reduce_string[i-=2] = full_string[i+=1];` undefined behaviour.

Comment: Why oh why are you reading filenames from stdin instead of taking command line arguments!?  Just imagine if tools like `grep` worked that way.

Comment: Even if it wasn't UB, you never null-terminate reduce_string, and you read uninitialized memory if the source string was shorter than the buffer size. Not to mention all the potential buffer overflows

Comment: You do things in a hard manner, while you could do it in a way easier manner: Just `fgetc` one of every 3 characters of the first file and print them, one by one, in the other file. Things are simple as that.

Comment: You should check that the `fopen()` calls succeed.  People are awful about typing things like names of non-existent files, or files they can't read or write.  You could simplify the code by reading character by character, and only printing every Nth character.

Comment: However, it seems that you should know (if it not already the case) that scanf can be very harmful. Just search something like "why is scanf bad?" or "Why shouldn't I use scanf?" on the Internet and you will learn a lot about it.

Comment: You mean something like [A beginners' guide away from `scanf()`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html), @nounoursnoir

Comment: @JonathanLeffler exactly

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Check this code out. In your code, you have `reduce_string[i-=2] = full_string[i+=1];` — I don't know where you come up with it, but this was not working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 int main ()
 {
    int i;
    char full_string[100];
    char reduce_string[100];

    char file_name_for_read[128];
    char file_name_for_save[128];

    printf("Enter file name for read...\n");
    scanf ("%s", file_name_for_read);

    strcat(file_name_for_read,".txt");
    FILE *fileA;
    fileA=fopen(file_name_for_read,"r");

    printf("Enter file name for save...\n");
    scanf ("%s", file_name_for_save);

    strcat(file_name_for_save,".txt");
    FILE *fileB;
    fileB=fopen(file_name_for_save,"w");

    while(fgets(full_string, 50, fileA) !=NULL)
    {
         int cnt = 0;
        for(i = 2; i < strlen(full_string)-3; i+=3)
        {
            reduce_string[cnt++] = full_string[i];
        }
        fprintf(fileB, "%s", reduce_string);
    }

    fclose(fileA);
    fclose(fileB);

}
```

Comment: This code does not null terminate the reduced string.  What's written to file isn't accurate in general.  (The `for (i = 2; i < strlen(full_string) - 3; i += 3)` control with `strlen()` being evaluated on each iteration is bad practice too.)

Comment: 1) Curious to use 50 in `char full_string[100]; .... fgets(full_string, 50,`  2) `i < strlen(full_string)-3` is _very bad_ code should `strlen(full_string)` be 2 or less. (hint:  `strlen(full_string)-3` is a very large number) 3) reading a _null character_ will mess things up.

Comment: Detail: Problem with `int i;... i < strlen(full_string)-3`.  `strlen()` returns a `size_t`, some unsigned type.  If it returned 2, `(size_t)i < ((size_t)2)-3` is `i<SIZE_MAX`, which is certainly true and the loop will certainly attempt to access outside `reduce_string[]` which is UB. A "fix" would use `i + 3 < strlen(full_string)` yet other problems remain.

Answer (score 8):

> What am I doing wrong?

Several things.  At minimum,

- In your inner loop, you iterate over the full length of `full_string`, regardless of how many of those bytes were actually read from the file by the most recent `fgets()`.
- In your inner loop, you invoke undefined behavior because the expression `reduce_string[i-=2] = full_string[i+=1]` has two side effects on the value of `i` that are unsequenced relative to each other.
- In that expression, `i - 2` is anyway not the index you want except when `i` is 2, because you increment `i` by 3 at each iteration.  You'll end up filling some positions and skipping others.
- You do not add a null terminator at the end of the data copied into `reduce_string`.
- Your strategy does not anyway result in copying every third character *of the file*; rather, it copies every third character *of each line*.  These differ unless all the line lengths of the input files are multiples of 3.

Answer (score 2):

> reads file A and then copies the contents to file B. I would like to write to file B every third character.

If *lines* are not important,
seems simple to read 3 characters and write the 3rd one.

```
for(;;) {
  fgetc(fileA);
  fgetc(fileA);
  int ch = fgetc(fileA);
  if (ch == EOF) break;
  fputc(ch, fileB);
}
```

or

```
int ch;
do {
  fgetc(fileA);
  fgetc(fileA);
  ch = fgetc(fileA);
} while (ch != EOF && fputc(ch, fileB) != EOF);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a different index for each array, that way each can go at their own speed.

```
int i,x;

for(i = 0, x=0; i < 1000; i+=3, x++)
{
    reduce_string[x] = full_string[i];
}
fprintf(fileB, "%s", reduce_string);
```

Comment: Please explain things instead of just showing a block of code; I think this is not a good answer. The question was "What am I doing wrong?", not "Please show me how to do this"

Comment: You don't null terminate the reduced string.  It isn't wholly clear where the 1000 comes from.